# If structure to compare result of two commands

Tags: bash, if-statement

I want to compare result of two commands in bash like so:

```
if `cat /root/pid` == `ps aux | grep "python" | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`
then
   <SomeCommands>
else
   <OtherCommands>
fi
```

I want to check if the result of `cat /root/pid` and `ps aux | grep "python" | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'` is equal or not.

I also want to check if specific `command` is running in my server or not. This method I think works. Any other methods are welcome.

Thank you

Comment: The result of `cat /root/pid` and `ps aux | grep "python" | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`

Comment: So what exactly prevents you from doing that?

Comment: `Val1=$(command1); Val2=$(command2) if [[ "$Val1" == "$Val2" ]]`

Comment: A tip: `grep "python" | grep -v grep` can be replaced by `grep [p]ython` :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
[[ "$(cat /root/pid)" == "$(ps aux | grep 'python' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')" ]]
```

Though I believe you can cut down both `grep` and do all using `awk` itself.

Comment: Yes `if [[ "$(cat /root/pid)" == "$(ps aux | grep "python" | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')" ]]; then echo "matched"; fi` is also correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
if [[ "$(cat /root/pid)" == "$(ps aux | grep "python" | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')" ]]
then
<SomeCommands>
else
<OtherCommands>
fi
```

Your if command is syntactically incorrect as it does not contain `[[` `[` or `((` brackets around it, also probably best to doublequote the commands so they are read as a whole string

Answer (score 1):

You can make it even shorter:

```
   if  [ "$(cat /root/pid)" == "$(pidof python)" ]; then
        <someCommands>
   else
        <otherCommands>
   fi
```